# Popup with POST method Invokes in the test Azure but fails in the real Azure

Tags: javascript, asp.net, silverlight, azure

I want my Silverlight cloudapp to use the SSRS Reportviewer control hosted in a WebForm called Reportviewer.aspx, and this is working well from the test Azure "127.0.0.1" environment when Invoking the javascript OpenReportviewer function from my SL C# class:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OpenReportViewer(ReportViewerURL, TabHeading, EstId, ShowExtraDetail, ReportTypeID, PreExpandSections) {
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.action = ReportViewerURL;   //'http://endorphin.cloudapp.net/Reporting/ReportViewer.aspx';
        form.method = "POST";
        form.target = '_blank'; // this is important to open a new window 

        var tabHeading = document.createElement('input');
        tabHeading.name = 'TabHeading';
        tabHeading.value = TabHeading;
        form.appendChild(tabHeading);

        var estID = document.createElement('input');
        estID.name = 'EstID';
        estID.value = EstId;
        form.appendChild(estID);

        var showExtraDetail = document.createElement('input');
        showExtraDetail.name = 'ShowExtraDetail';
        showExtraDetail.value = ShowExtraDetail;
        form.appendChild(showExtraDetail);

        var reportTypeID = document.createElement('input');
        reportTypeID.name = 'ReportTypeID';
        reportTypeID.value = ReportTypeID;
        form.appendChild(reportTypeID);

        var preExpandSections = document.createElement('input');
        preExpandSections.name = 'PreExpandSections';
        preExpandSections.value = PreExpandSections;
        form.appendChild(preExpandSections);

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(form);
      } 
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {...
```

However I've now deployed to the real Azure and it says: "Failed to Invoke: OpenReportviewer"

The above function is now pasted exactly.

The calling code is:

```
//**********************************************************************************
public void Invoke3(string tabHeading, int estID, int reportTypeID, bool showExtraDetail, bool preExpandSections)
{
  if (true == HtmlPage.IsPopupWindowAllowed)
  {
    string strBaseWebAddress = App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri;
    int PositionOfClientBin =
        App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().IndexOf(@"/clientbin");
    strBaseWebAddress = Strings.Left(strBaseWebAddress, PositionOfClientBin);
    string ReportViewerURL = String.Format(@"{0}/Reporting/ReportViewer.aspx", strBaseWebAddress);

    try
    {
      HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("OpenReportViewer", ReportViewerURL, tabHeading, estID.ToString(),
                            showExtraDetail.ToString(), reportTypeID.ToString(), preExpandSections.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      My.ShowError("Failed to invoke Webform for Report Viewer.", ex);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("You must enable popups to view reports. Safari browser is not supported.",
        "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
  }
}
```

Comment: pasting the code you use to invoke that script would be helpful. Did you try debugging the JS with either FireBug, or DeveloperTools or Google Chrome's console?

Comment: No - it worked in local Azure, and JS debugging is a new learning curve for me.  Can you recommend the easiest/best way?   I tried enabling script debugging in IE, but execution does not stop on a breakpoint in my JS code with VS 2010..  (Thanks again)

Comment: If you are **pasting** the code, then your issue is the letter **v** in the function name. You have defined it with small "v" (OpenReport**v**iewer) in the JavaScript, but you are trying to call it with Capital "V" in the C# code - HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("OpenReport**V**iewer", .... Double check the function names in both places!

Comment: That was not it.  Apologies for the incorrect adaptation of the JS routine.  Now both routines are pasted.  I've now tried also adding the JS routine to the hosting html file as well as the hosting aspx file (ok long shot).  Anyway that was also not it.

I confirm it works ok when I hit F5 in the Azure project in VS2010, but fails to invoke when deployed to Azure after no changes.  This is the new deployment: 

http://c366a2f51815411fa021661c6ea47aa9.cloudapp.net/

Comment: BTW I'm still using SL4.  Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. The difference between the local Azure and real Azure could be the security zone.
2. There could be some hard coded link that points to the local Azure.

Comment: .Net trust level is set to Full trust.  The only link (unless there's something outside my code that I'm unaware of) is provided by my ReportViewerURL parameter above.